# How to interpret BUFR descriptors

Tags: coordinate-system, remote-sensing, metadata, resolution

I'm processing BUFR products from Eumetsat and I would like to ask for your help about the following descriptors:

```
002028 SEGMENT SIZE AT NADIR IN X DIRECTION
002029 SEGMENT SIZE AT NADIR IN Y DIRECTION
```

My problem is that I don't know how to interpret their values.

For example in ASR (All sky radiance) product from MSG, I have this subset in the first message of the bufr file:

```
:Subset 1
:
:     1  001007               57  SATELLITE IDENTIFIER [CODE TABLE]
:     2  001031              254  IDENTIFICATION OF ORIGINATING/GENERATING CENTRE: [CODE TABLE]
:     3  002020              333  SATELLITE CLASSIFICATION [CODE TABLE]
:
     4  002028            48000  SEGMENT SIZE AT NADIR IN X-DIRECTION [M]
:     5  002029            48000  SEGMENT SIZE AT NADIR IN Y-DIRECTION [M]
:     6  004001             2015  YEAR [A]
:     7  004002                2  MONTH [MON]
:     8  004003               27  DAY [D]
:     9  004004               20  HOUR [H]
:    10  004005               45  MINUTE [MIN]
:    11  004006                0  SECOND [S]
:    12  005001         23.46664  LATITUDE (HIGH ACCURACY) [DEG]
:    13  006001         -59.6647  LONGITUDE (HIGH ACCURACY) [DEG]
:    14  030021             3712  NUMBER OF PIXELS PER ROW [NUMERIC]
:    15  030022             3712  NUMBER OF PIXELS PER COLUMN [NUMERIC]
:    16  010002          missing  HEIGHT [M]
:    17  020082               62  AMOUNT SEGMENT CLOUD FREE [%]
:    18  008012                1  LAND/SEA QUALIFIER [CODE TABLE]
:    19  020082                0  AMOUNT SEGMENT CLOUD FREE [%]
:    20  008012          missing  LAND/SEA QUALIFIER [CODE TABLE]
:    21  020081               38  CLOUD AMOUNT IN SEGMENT [%]
:    22  008003                8  VERTICAL SIGNIFICANCE (SATELLITE OBSERVATIONS) :[CODE TABLE]
:    23  020081               38  CLOUD AMOUNT IN SEGMENT [%]
:    24  008003                9  VERTICAL SIGNIFICANCE (SATELLITE OBSERVATIONS) :[CODE TABLE]
:    25  020081                0  CLOUD AMOUNT IN SEGMENT [%]
```

As you can see, in this subset we have a single point with a LATITUDE and LONGITUDE. I interpret a subset as a description of a single segment and as above this segment has a single coordinates and a single value for a certain data type.
So I get that segment = pixel. And so pixel has a dimension of 48000m x 48000m as written in the subset. Is this right? Why I read also:

```
:    14  030021             3712  NUMBER OF PIXELS PER ROW [NUMERIC]
:    15  030022             3712  NUMBER OF PIXELS PER COLUMN [NUMERIC]
```

If a pixel has the dimension above we can't have an image size of 3712 x 3712. Also I know that MSG has a pixel resolution of 3km x 3km and 1km x 1km not 48km x 48km.

Any ideas please?

Comment: 1 bufr pixel = 16x16 MSG pixel :)

Comment: Hi Marco, could you please post your solution as an **Answer** instead of adding "SOLVED" to your title? When you post your answer, you can click the green tick to close this question off (note: you will have to wait 2 days from when you first posted your question).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved with:

1 bufr pixel = 16x16 MSG pixel, then the size is (3712 / 16) x (3712 / 16) = 232 x 232 pixels :)